# Difference between direct sum and Cartesian product in terms of finite dimensional vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

There have been some responses on this topic but they are in the language of group theory for which I am not well versed.

Take a bilinear form acting in $\mathcal{V}$ for example. Is it a map from $\mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, or is it a map from $\mathcal{V} \oplus \mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$? Further, why is the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ typically considered $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and not $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$? The inkling I have is that the direct sum preserves some kind of additive structure while the Cartesian product does not?

My understanding is that the direct sum between two vector spaces is an ordered pair with the first element from the first vector space and the second element from the second vector space. But then the Cartesian product isn't exactly an ordered pair. It is considered a vector in a new space. For example, if $ {\bf x} \in\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$, then ${\bf x} = ({\bf u}, {\bf v})$, where ${\bf u} \in \mathbb{R}$ and ${\bf v} \in \mathbb{R}$. If $ {\bf x} \in\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, then ${\bf x} = {\bf x}$, where ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Can someone help clear this up for me $ \bf \text {in the context of finite dimensional vector spaces}$?

Answer (score 3):

Vector spaces are special in that given two vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then $V \oplus W$ and $V \times W$ are naturally isomorphic. This is only true when we take a finite number of products/summands, and I encourage you to write out the "obvious" isomorphism. I think your interpretation of $V \times W$ is a little restricting. Recall that $(v,w) \in V \times W$ is a vector and the addition on $V \times W$ is defined component-wise, i.e. $$(v,w)+(v',w') = (v+v',w+w')$$